# can not show the sign up succesfully when using firebase database

Tags: java, android, xml

I am writing the code for sign up using the firebase.

The account creates but it always execute the else part of the file. plz help me

I do cross check every line even debugg too. but I can't solve the problem.

```java
package com.e.freshfuits;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.e.freshfuits.model.User;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

import java.net.UnknownServiceException;


public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextInputEditText editname,editpassword,editphone;
    private Button btnsignup;
    final FirebaseDatabase 
        firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference 
    table_user=firebaseDatabase.getReference("User");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
        editphone=(TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.editphone);
        editname=(TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.editname);
        editpassword=(TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        btnsignup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signupbutton);

    }

    public void mymethod(View view) {

        final ProgressDialog mDialog=new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this);
        mDialog.setMessage("Please wait ! ");
        mDialog.show();

        table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.child(editphone.getText().toString()).exists()) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Already Registered ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    User user=new User(editname.getText().toString(),editpassword.getText().toString());
                    table_user.child(editphone.getText().toString()).setValue(user);
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Account Created sucessfully ! ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Instead of one time if block execution, it executes else part too. and show the message, user already exists. and on other side the account is creating.

Comment: Is dosen't show an error? Could you be more specific if It shows any error?

Answer (score 0):

For checking if the user is signed in or not you have to authenticate with Firebase.

Firebase Database is only for storing the data, it can't check the user is signed in or not or like that other things.

```
FirebaseAuth auth;
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

then you have to get the user from auth if it's null then the user is not signed in

```
FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser(); //method
```

Below code is for signUp the user:-

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                updateUI(user);
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }
            // ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanku for the information... its really help... i m working on firebase-database 10.2.0 , this could also creates problem.. now problem is solved.. thanku sir